# Send 2 args to Celery eta task

Tags: python, django, celery

I use eta to program a task:

```
test.apply_async(eta=datetime(2019, 8, 4, 17, 01))
```

but I have a task on test.py that take an arg from view, for example 'post':

```
app = Celery()
@app.task(bind=True)
def test(post, self):
    #somecode
```

I need to pass 'eta' and 'post',
I try with:

```
test.apply_async(post, eta=datetime(2019, 8, 4, 17, 01))
```

but give an error:

```
functools.partial object argument after * must be an iterable, not Author
```

what's wrong?

EDIT1

Try:

```
test.apply_async(args=(post.id,) eta=datetime(2019, 8, 4, 17, 01))
```

It try to run task:

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def test(post, self):
    takeit = Author.objects.get(pk=post)
    print takeit
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 382, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 641, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "pathto/test.py", line 122, in test
    takeit = Author.objects.get(pk=post)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 371, in get
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 784, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 802, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1250, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1276, in _add_q
    allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1210, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1104, in build_lookup
    return final_lookup(lhs, rhs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 74, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 966, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'test'
```

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply_async

Comment: yes, but I not find the solution....

Comment: I try to pass ```test.apply_async(args=(post.id,) eta=datetime(2019, 8, 4, 17, 01))``` another error

Comment: The first parameter to the task definition should be self `def test(self, post_id):`

Comment: Perfect, it work!! TY @IainShelvington u're great!!!

Comment: But now when in test.py i go to call a chrome driver `driver =webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=opts)` give an error: `TypeError: environment can only contain strings
` what's happened?

Answer (score 1):

You made one of the common Python typos...

You have `def test(post, self):` where it should really be `def test(self, post):`. It typically happens when doing some code refactoring...